# Select for JSON return array of string arrays (not array of objects)

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, datatables

I have a query formatted to return as JSON.  It returns an array of objects.

```
select id, name from [user] 
for JSON auto
```

Here's the array of **objects** it returns

```
[{
        "id": "0FDF9BCA-1E41-4DA6-B892-0017DE395754",
        "name": "I Accept Answers"
    }, {
        "id": "3E775870-D97A-4B23-B761-00382D932704",
        "name": "Heywood Youhelpme"
    },{
        "id": "4E775870-D97A-4B23-B761-00382D932704",
        "name": "Geeimiss Xml"
    }
 ]
```

However the objects names are overkill in a large homogeneous data set.  I just want the data (no object names).

```
[
    [
        "0FDF9BCA-1E41-4DA6-B892-0017DE395754",
        "I Accept Answers"
    ],
    [
        "3E775870-D97A-4B23-B761-00382D932704",
        "Heywood Youhelpme"
    ],
    [
        "4E775870-D97A-4B23-B761-00382D932704",
        "Geeimiss Xml"
    ]
]
```

I'm hoping to provide this as a AJAX response to browser side DataTables.js display.

I've seen several "really" messy solutions that really mess-up the query, I'm hoping there's some "as array" option or similar in the "for JSON" instruction.  Nothing that required special instructions for every parameter.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU5) (KB4092643) - 14.0.3023.8 (X64)   Mar  2 2018 18:24:44   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're requesting a javascript solution. If so, you can use `Object.values` like this :

```js
var json = '[{"id": "0FDF9BCA-1E41-4DA6-B892-0017DE395754","name": "I Accept Answers"}, {"id": "3E775870-D97A-4B23-B761-00382D932704","name": "Heywood Youhelpme"},{"id": "4E775870-D97A-4B23-B761-00382D932704","name": "Geeimiss Xml"} ]';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var values = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return  Object.values(obj[key]); });
console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
```

IF you need an SQL Server 2017 solution, `FOR JSON` will always return JSON objects, so to have arrays, you'll need to create it manually :

```
SELECT RESULT = '[' + STRING_AGG( ISNULL('[ "' + id + '","'+ Name '" ]', ''), ',') + ']'
FROM 
    [user]
```

Comment: Sorry, no.  I'm looking for a SQL solution.  I'm trying to get just the data I want to the browser, not fix it in the browser.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth I have updated my answer with SQL solution.

Comment: Thanks iSR5, but where does @JSON come from? I'm starting with a SQL query, and want to build JSON with that's an Array of Arrays.  SQL already builds arrays of objects, which is what you're building too. I have dozens of existing queries to change, so I can't re-build them all with this string manipulation.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth `@JSON` is your current json results (that is already converted from the table using `select id, name from [user] for JSON auto`, and the result of the above query would return arrays of object values (in this case I'm only returning `name` values as array).

Comment: @WilliamWalseth I'm sorry, I've updated my answer again, this time I've removed the previous solution, since you don't need to use `FOR JSON` as you want to return arrays of arrays, while SQL Server will return objects only. So direct select with help of `STRING_AGG` would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still hoping for something that won't require re-writing all my queries.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth you could do a custom function either a TVF or Scalar.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a query like below which uses [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) AND [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) functions of tsql in tandem

```
select  
    '[' + 
       STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(id,'"')+','+QUOTENAME(name,'"')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),',')
      +']' 
from [user]
```

and this will work too

```
select  '['+
STRING_AGG(CAST(CONCAT('["', id ,'","' , name,'"]') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),',')
+']' from [user]
```

You may want to try this if you need a wrapper around JSON output

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((select id, name from [user] 
for JSON auto),'[{','[['),'}]',']]'),'},{','],[')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really trying to avoid this sort of messy solution that requires changing the entire query.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth you'd need a cast. Updating query 1

Comment: Dhruv, thanks you're a real expert in string processing to come up with these so quickly, but this really isn't the direction I'm hoping for.  Does MSSQL support this natively with some sort of option?

Comment: @WilliamWalseth Not that I know of.